# bash - aliased command - use original command?

Tags: bash, alias

I have `ls` aliased to `ls` and some flags, however, I want to use the original, 'vanilla' version of `ls` in another alias. Is there a way for me to call the original version of `ls`?

Comment: \ls will also use the unaliased version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could run `command ls` or use the full path to it explicitly like `/bin/ls`

If you specify the full path you won't be using any functions or aliases.  Similarly, `command` can find the executable with the given name without doing normal function/alias lookups.  See `help command` for more